# SQL (PHP) with group by and cross column comparison

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table:

```
+======+=========+============+======+======+
| name | surname | other_name | year | date |
+======+=========+============+======+======+
| John |   Foo   |    NULL    | 2000 | 2017 |
+------+---------+------------+------+------+
| John |   Foo   |    Bar     | 2000 | 2018 |
+------+---------+------------+------+------+
| John |   Bar   |    NULL    | 2000 | 2018 |
+------+---------+------------+------+------+
| John |   Bar   |    Bar     | 2000 | 2018 |
+------+---------+------------+------+------+
| John |   Foo   |    NULL    | 1990 | 2018 |
+------+---------+------------+------+------+
```

I'm trying to group the records for same person. **Same person is identified by `name`, `surname` and `year`** of birth.

One can however change his surname (Foo -> Bar). Then the old rows' `other_name` column should be updated with the new name. Unfortunately the data I have are incomplete and when one changed his name, the `other_name` might have been updated, but it also might not.

I can easily `group by` the three basic columns.

What I need to do as well though is to **cross compare the `surname` and `other_name` and if they match and so do the `name` and `year` columns, group them under the most recent surname** (decided by `date` when the row was recorded).

The final print result should look like this:

```
+======+===========+======+
| name |  surname  | year |
+======+===========+======+
| John | Bar (Foo) | 2000 |
+------+-----------+------+
| John |    Foo    | 1990 |
+------+-----------+------+
```

I realize it's rather a complex task for an SQL query. So if you have a simpler solution accomplished in the program (PHP), I would appreciate it as well.

Comment: Can people change their names multiple times?  If so, it would be helpful if the sample data showed better examples.

Comment: Let's say they, can't. I updated the example output.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This does what you want in the limited case that surnames are only changed once:

```
select t.name, t.year, group_concat(distinct t.surname) as surnames
from t left join
     t tother
     on t.surname = tother.other_name and t.name = tother.name and t.year = tother.year
group by t.name, t.year, coalesce(tother.surname, t.surname);
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f59df7ac30c817ca6eaad3900d1bb88e) (it uses Postgres because I find that easier to set up but all is the same except the `group_concat()`).

Comment: I tried it with all data and it didn't work as expected. So I dived a bit deeper and found another case, where the new `surname` is also filled in the `other_name` ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e1d5b4d1e6a13a7cca79e9f5c584674f)). In that case I get an additional unwanted row.